# What is the proof-theoretic significance of the existence of a Brown-Palsberg self-interpreter for system $F_\omega$?

Tags: type-theory, proof-theory

In [A Self-Interpreter for F-omega](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/paper/popl16-full.pdf), Brown and Palsberg construct for each term of each type $x:T$ a representation $\bar x : \Box T$ (a metatheoretical function which can't be represented in the language), and an interpretation function $u_T : \Box T \to T$. This is reminiscent of GL provability logic, which in particular abstracts how PA can represent its own proof theory. But while the representation looks like the axiom $\vdash T \implies \vdash \Box T$, the second $\vdash \Box T \to T$ is inconsistent with GL.

So what sort of gadget is this, in logical terms?

Can it be used at all to talk about the metatheory of F-omega?

What would a representation operation that satisfies the axioms of GL look like?

Comment: This might be closer to Artemov's "logic of proofs" than to GL.

Answer (score 8):

There is no proof significance, since already [Gödel's $T$ has a Brown-Palsberg self-interpreter for free](http://math.andrej.com/2016/01/04/a-brown-palsberg-self-interpreter-for-godels-system-t/). We need a better definition of a typed self-interpreter.

Comment: But what about their "deep" interpreter? They seem to be able to do non-trivial things with it. For example, they have a normalization checker, which usually implies a proof of consistency of a type theory.

Comment: Their interpreter seems to have some structurally desirable properties, but their *definition* of interpreter allows for trivial solutions, such as the one linked to in my answer.  As far as I can tell nothing much is going on here. For instance, the normalization checker is just a simple recursion on the structure of the term.